# Matplotlib and numpy: error in plotting infinite numbers on x-axis (pyzo)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of values, where some of the values need to be converted before plotting with matplotlib.

The expression looks as follows:

```
m=0
while m < len(power):
        for item in power:
            if float(list1[m]) != 0:
                list2.append(float((1/float(list1[m])-1)*float(power[m])))
            elif float(list1[m]) == 0:
                list2.append("inf")
            m+=1
```

Where "power" is a list of values between 0 and 100+ (one decimal) and list1 can be anything between a negative value, 0 or a positive value (four decimals).

As you can see, to avoid getting zero division I have a condition to get an asymptotic behavior if list1 = 0.

This works fine, and plots fine, for the y axis. However, if I try to plot the same thing on the x axis I get the following warning:

```
[...]\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py:504: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
return np.alltrue(x[1:] - x[0:-1] >= 0)
[...]\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py:504: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
return np.alltrue(x[1:] - x[0:-1] >= 0)
```

From what I can see, the plot looks fine (perhaps there is some problem that I'm not seeing) but I want to avoid getting a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say what is wrong with your plotting code if you do not give us your plotting code! But let's have a try:

```
%pylab
power = randint(1, 100, 10)
list1 = randn(10)
list2 = []

m=0
while m < len(power):
        for item in power:
            if float(list1[m]) != 0:
                list2.append(float((1/float(list1[m])-1)*float(power[m])))
            elif float(list1[m]) == 0:
                list2.append("inf")
            m+=1

plot(t, list2)
plot(list2, t)
```

That seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. The code is around 500 lines and divided into objects and classes so I tried to abbreviate it somewhat. Also I do not have access to pylab, only matplotlib. List1 is something like 1700 values, typically 0.000 to 0.7500. The plot itself is: "plt.plot(arg_x,arg_y, linetype, color=colortype)" where arg_x == list2 in this case.

Comment: Sorry I checked again and I do have access to pylab. Code still produces the same error however.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the correct way to handle this, but it seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr('ignore')
```

Voila. No warnings printed. I suppose this could be a risk if something would go wrong, but from what I can see, it plots just fine.